# Display inline Gridview, Detailsview and div with text

Tags: html, asp.net, css, gridview

I have problem with positioning.I Have a gridview and a details view and a div with some text. I want to show these 3 things inline and when the window become smaller the things automaticaly must be one thing under the other.
This is the Details view css:

```
  .cssdetailsview {  text-align:center;width:125px;position:relative;}
```

This is the Gridview css:

```
  .grid-viewPlayers {    
width:250px;
position:relative;display:inline-block;}
```

And this is the sidebar css

```
.sidebar {
float: right;
width: 190px;
padding: 0 15px 20px 15px;}
```

The gridview and the detailsview is inside a div with css:

```
   .GridContent {
text-align: left;
width: auto;
display:inline-block; }
```

I am trying using span but it is not working.

asp is:

```
    <div class="GridContent">

    <span>
<asp:GridView>.... </span>
    <span>
<asp:DetailsView>.... </span>
 </div>
 <div class="sidebar">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</div>
```

It displays the gridview under the detailsview and next to each other.Any suggestions to show inline without window resizing problems???

Answer (score 0):

try to use table structure In Html :
Example :

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> <asp:GridView/>  </td>
<td> <asp:DetailsView/> </td>
<td> textContent  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes this is working but when I resize the window to smaller the items are still inline and don't be under each other.Is there any technique to do this using table?

Comment: I did it but in window resize the items are still next to eachother an not over eachother